# HTTP POST from Angular 5 (to get a JWT) returns NULL in the Response

Tags: angular, rest, jwt

I have a REST Login Operation that has been written in Java (for the server side). `JWT (Jason Web Token)` is also used.

The client side is using the HTTP client under `Angular 5` to access / execute the `REST API`.

What is taking place is that the Login REST functionality (using HTTP client) is executed. Afterwards, information is returned and the Return Code Status is 200 (meaning everything is OK).

According to the Chrome Browser "Network" tab, the RC comes back with a 200. Also, the token is in the header

[image]

Even though this is the case, the Response is set to NULL.

**code ran**

```
[ ... snip ...]

return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {

        console.log( "==>  looking for the answer - begin ");
        console.log( response );
        console.log( "==>  looking for the answer - end ");

[ ... snip ...]
```

**values produced in Console**

```
NgForm {submitted: true, _directives: Array(2), ngSubmit: EventEmitter, form: FormGroup}control: (...)controls: (...)dirty: (...)disabled: (...)enabled: (...)errors: (...)form: FormGroup {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: false, touched: true, …}formDirective: (...)invalid: (...)ngSubmit: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}path: (...)pending: (...)pristine: (...)status: (...)statusChanges: (...)submitted: truetouched: (...)untouched: (...)valid: (...)value: (...)valueChanges: (...)_directives: (2) [NgModel, NgModel]__proto__: ControlContainer
admin-login.component.ts:72  getting ready to go call the service 
admin-login.component.ts:76  values for id and password terrencedarby ----- 3333333333
admin-services.service.ts:175 ==>  looking for the answer - begin 
admin-services.service.ts:176 null
admin-services.service.ts:177 ==>  looking for the answer - end
```

**QUESTION:**
Why is this the case?

TIA

**Current Angular Version**

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.23
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

**admin-services.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from 'app/pages/auth-admin/_admin-model/user';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Services } from '@angular/core/src/view';
import { ImplicitReceiver, componentFactoryName } from '@angular/compiler';
import { not } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/defer';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/expand';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/let';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishReplay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/shareReplay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/reduce';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


import * as JWT from 'jwt-decode';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';


export const ANONYMOUS_USER: User = {
  id: undefined
}


[... snip ...]

  adminLogin(username, password): Observable<boolean> {
    let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
    let tokenResp = {};

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {

        // login successful if there's a token in the response
        let token = response.json() && response.json().token;

        if (token) {

          let t = JWT(token);

          console.log("-- what is in the token --");
          console.log(t);

          //initiialize
          let setUser: User = ANONYMOUS_USER;

          // need to set the value here
          this.userLoggedIn.next(setUser);

          // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          // => SET BACK: localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.userLoggedIn));
          // => SET BACK: this.userLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

          // return true to indicate successful login
          return true;
        } else {
          // throw an error that the token was "whack"
          return Observable.throw(
            new Error("APX: the token was not set properly"));
        }
        //return response.json();
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);

        if (e.status === 401) {
          return Observable.throw(
            new Error("Error Code : 401 - Unauthorized Access To Server "));
        }

        return Observable.throw(
          new Error( "Unexpected Error Code: " + e.status ));
      });
  }
[... snip ...]
```

Comment: I faced the same issue, probably your problem is in the backend side, the token is been returning but without body content. Are you using Spring Security? If yes, show me your TokenAuthenticationService that I can point you what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the full response, not just body. Please refer to [HTTP client documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response). Your post call should be like that:

```
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })
    .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks will try this - but - there is no body. There seems to be only a Header. There is no Cookie either. But - will try this and update this with my results.

Comment: HttpResponse contains all the data from your actual response: header, body (if present or null), etc.

Comment: Thanks again - got the response info, where can I find the token?

Comment: By acessing headers, via response.headers https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse